# How to assign a variable to flutter Navigator.push(context, variable);

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

I tried to assign it a string
String variable = "'/branchHome'";
Navigator.push(context, variable);
but it doesn't work with the error

`Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Route<Object>'.`

I tried doing this
`Navigator.push(context, variable as Route);`

That didn't work either

How do i assign a variable to Route name in dart

Edit :
**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => Loading(),
      '/home': (context) => Home(),
      '/studentHome': (context) => studentHome(),
      '/getAllstudents': (context) => getAllStudent(),
      '/examHome': (context) => getAllBranch(),
      '/branchHome': (context) => branchHome(),
      '/subjectHome': (context) => subjectHome(),
    },
  ));
}
```

**list**

```
List<Info> slides = [
  Info(
    1,
    name: 'Branches',
    desc: "branches info",
    url: "'/branchHome'",
  ),
  Info(
    2,
    name: 'Exams',
    desc: "exam info",
    url: "'/examHome'",
  ),
];
```

what i tried

```
 onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, slides[index].url);
                },
```

and

```
 onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, slides[index].url as Route);
                },
```

Comment: are you trying to pass an object to the next screen?

Comment: No Im just trying to go to the next screen using variables

Comment: I have a list of routes and made a list of cards using listview builder im trying to assign the route as a variable

Comment: The route name ..

Comment: have you mentioned "'/branchHome'" in route in your material app? Share that code too

Comment: yup I did mention it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Navigator.pushNamed<dynamic>(context, slides[index].url);
```

this works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute below code..

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/branchHome');
```

Before that in **main.dart** file you have to give reference of your route string.

e.g.

```
return new MaterialApp(
      title: "MyApp",
      home: new HomePage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
      },
```

Comment: I have a list of routes how do I assign it using variables

Answer (score 0):

In you `main.dar` add this lines

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Named Routes Demo',
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      
      '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
     
      '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
      '/third': (context) => thirdScreen(),
    },
  ));
}
```

In your Navigator Route

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
```

Comment: what's your listview is like...?@sonuishaq

Comment: It has an itembuilder and a few children with styling nothing related to this question

Comment: what i assume you are tryint to do,that you have listview contains  `Branches` and  `Exams`, when you press `Branches`,it need to got to next screen, are you trying to do like this...?@sonuishaq

Comment: is your branches and exam is comes from api  or just hard coded view  @sonuishaq

Comment: Its from an Api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219693/discussion-between-morbius-black-and-sonu-ishaq).